# JMeter: How to stop test if I receive a message in error queue

Tags: jmeter

Our application has an output queue and a error queue too. When a error occurs, a reply message is put in output queue and the original message is put in error queue.

I've setup the following test plan:

1. Thread group with X users

   - Publisher sending messages to input queue
2. Thread group with X users

   - Subscriber receiving messages from output queue
3. Thread group with 1 user

   - Subscriber receiving messages from error queue

I want to stop the test if any message has been received in error queue. Moreover, stop the thread when the 2nd thread group has finished. Is that possible?

An alternative could be to add an assertion in the 2nd thread group to assert the content of each reply (if contains code "ok" or not), but that won't be good for the performance test itself, right? Adding a separate thread monitoring the error queue sounds better to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe adding a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) is kind of more "lightweight" than setting up a separate thread group which will be sending JMS messages, however it depends on your particular test implementation, you can measure the resources consumption using a [Java profiler tool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

With regards to your questions, you can listen the error queue in a loop using [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and if any message appears it will break the "while" loop and put a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler below the While Controller configured to stop the test

Similarly in the "main" thread group you can put Flow Control Action sampler as the "last" sampler so it will terminate the test when the main scenario ends.

Example setup:

[image]